# Unable to run pandas python script via batch file

Tags: python, pandas, batch-file, ssis

I created a `CleanCSV.py` script file with pandas package to clean my csv file (after a long try with csv package I could do it only with pandas package). I am new to python scripting.

script file content below. It worked in IDE (Visual Studio). but failed when called from command line.

```
import pandas

filepath_i = 'C:\Source Files\PatientRecords.csv'
filepath_o = 'C:\Source Files\PatientRecords2.csv'
df = pandas.read_csv(filepath_i, delimiter =',', quotechar='"')
df['Provider Street Address'] = df['Provider Street Address'].str.replace(r'\r\n', '')
df['Provider Street Address'] = df['Provider Street Address'].str.replace(r'\n', '')
df['Provider Street Address'] = df['Provider Street Address'].str.replace(r'\r', '')
#print(df['Provider Street Address'][0:19])
df.to_csv(filepath_o,index=False)
```

This script worked fine. But when I tried to execute it from cmd prompt, its trowing below error. I need to call this script from batch process task in ssis.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.239]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64>python C:\Python\CleanCSV.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\CleanCSV.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper, NamedAgg
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.generic import (  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 44, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 88, in <module>
    from pandas.core.generic import NDFrame, _shared_docs
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 71, in <module>
    from pandas.io.formats.format import DataFrameFormatter, format_percentiles
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pandas.io.common import _expand_user, _stringify_path
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 7, in <module>
    from http.client import HTTPException  # noqa
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\http\client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\email\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\email\_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.utils import _has_surrogates
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\email\utils.py", line 29, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: WSAStartup failed: error code 10107

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64>
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.
[You should not post code as an image because:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Comment: How are you executing it? Could you show the content of the batch file?

Comment: @wwii replaced image with text.

Comment: @Valentino I didn't created a batch file yet, directly called py script from cmd prompt.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand then how can you claim that it worked fine.

Comment: @Valentino python script worked fine. when called from cmd prompt, it threw error. Did I miss any references?

Comment: I usually call python script from command line. How did you call it when it worked?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197305/discussion-between-gokul-and-valentino).